# ROS2 No module named 'tutorial_interfaces.tutorial_interfaces_s__rosidl_typesupport_c'

Tags: ros2

I'm trying to build a custom msg (following the tutorials) and I found myself stuck with the error "No module named 'tutorial_interfaces.tutorial_interfaces_s__rosidl_typesupport_c'" when trying to create a msg with the new type in Python.

Ros recognizes my msg type and I can use it with cpp. I imagine that it must be related with my current python installation (3.10.12). Do you have any clue of how could I fix it? I used to work with conda but as it is not supported along ros2 I disabled it and reinstalled ROS2, Could it be related with that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If someone has the same issues I managed to solve it by building ROS2 from source. I bet it had something to do with my python setup vs the one used to generate the debian package but I could not find the specefic cause of the error.